# Can I use my Go Card on Sunbus services in Cairns?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, australia, queensland, cairns

Public buses in Cairns seem to be operated by [Sunbus](http://www.sunbus.com.au/sit_cairns.htm), but they're part of the wider Queenland [Translink system](http://translink.com.au/cairns). There's a [special Translink website area for Cairns](http://translink.com.au/cairns), and a lot of the links from the Sunbus site for information take you back to the Translink site. The outside of the buses I've seen in Cairns all have Translink written on them.

Within the South-East Queensland area, it's generally recommended to get a [Go Card](http://translink.com.au/tickets-and-fares/go-card) to pay for your bus / train / etc trips. (It's much simpler and cheaper than using paper tickets). The [Go Card site](http://translink.com.au/tickets-and-fares/go-card) says

> go card is TransLink's South East Queensland electronic ticket. It allows you to travel seamlessly on all TransLink bus, train, ferry and tram services.

Cairns isn't in South-East Queenland, but it does have buses run on behalf of Translink (with Translink branding on the side), and the [Translink page on ticket pricing](http://translink.com.au/tickets-and-fares/fares/current-fares#C) covers both Cairns and SE-Queensland.

So, given all that, is a Go Card valid on buses in the Cairns area?

Comment: As of Sept 11 there were [no plans to introduce the go card in Cairns](https://m.facebook.com/TransLinkQLD/posts/964069906952408) (scroll down to the 2nd comment), so the answer is probably *no*. I actually took the bus in Cairns on a few occasions last April, but don't recall seeing any tag on/off equipment...

Comment: Any updates? I have noted that the GoCard equipment is installed in some Cairns Sunbuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Translink Go Card page](https://translink.com.au/tickets-and-fares/go-card) says

> Use go card on all TransLink bus, train (including Airtrain), ferry and tram services in greater Brisbane, Ipswich, Sunshine Coast, and Gold Coast regions.

So Go Card services have not yet extended beyond SE Queensland.

Comment: Some places say that the GoCard is valid on TransLink services in SE Queensland, some just say all TransLink services, hence the query!

Comment: The "all TransLink services" ones are due to the left hand not knowing what the right hand is doing, and assuming "TransLink" equals "SE Queensland" as it did for quite a while.  [The TransLink brand has only been up there since September](http://railbotforum.org/mbs/index.php?topic=10923.0).

Answer (score 2):

The name "TransLink" is a brand name owned by the State Government, however, most public transport bus services across the State are operated by private contractors to the State Government. This includes most public transport bus services in South East Queensland.
The public transport bus system in Cairns is operated by a contractor with blue buses all marked as TransLink, however, the GoCard is not valid in Cairns as of 24/04/2019.